# Docker Compose activate container on demand

Tags: docker, docker-compose, orchestration

I have an application that performs elaboration over a data feed. The process is divided into tasks so I structured a `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
task1-service: 
  image: task1-image
task2-service: 
  image: task2-image
task3-service: 
  image: task3-image
```

Each task-service is triggered by the end of the previous and triggers the next, then it can exit. So there's no point to keep each service running.

I wonder if there's a solution to keep them all stopped, and start each service on demand when needed. 
I don't know if `docker compose` is the correct solution, but I like the idea ok keeping the system described into one `yml` file. Anyway, other solutions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is possible to solve your approach in different ways, and one of them is with `docker-compose`.

First, you can start one concrete service (taskX-service) using `docker-compose up -d <service_name>`
You have more details in [docker-compose up for only certain containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233105/docker-compose-up-for-only-certain-containers)

Second, `docker-compose` also allows you to configure dependencies between containers. If you want to run them in order, you can specify it in `depends_on:` structure.
For example, to execute tasks 1, 2, and 3 in order you could use:

```
task1-service: 
  image: task1-image
task2-service: 
  image: task2-image
  depends_on:
    - task1-service
task3-service: 
  image: task3-image
  depends_on: 
    - task2-service
```

Furthermore, this docker-compose.yml is compatible with first I said:

```
docker-compose up -d task1-service
docker-compose up -d task2-service (also launchs task1-service)
docker-compose up -d task3-service (also launchs task2 and 1 service)
```

If you don't specify any container, with `docker-compose down` stops all containers in compose file.
I hope it's useful for you.

Comment: thanks @mulg0r, I'll give it a try. However, each service should be able to call for next task (or better, emit an event on wich someone listens). Dependency is just not the case: tasks should run separately and independently.

Comment: Ok, in this case you say, maybe is useful for you mount `volume: /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` launching services. So, you can launch docker containers/services from another container, not only from host, always you have installed docker daemon in them, of course

Comment: Be aware that `depends_on` only ensures that the other services will be started but does not wait for them to finish, i.e. this will start all services at once at not sequentially!
[In `docker-compose.yml` version 2.x you could use the `condition` form of `depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on) and a [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck) to force waiting until the other container is "ready" or done.