# How to docker-compose up only for services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my `docker-compose.yml` file I have plenty of services:

- nginx
- mysql
- redis
- echo
- php
- ...

But also some CLI utilities that I use with `docker-compose run --rm`:

- artisan
- composer
- npm
- ...

When I start my system I do `docker-compose up`. Unfortunately this also try to start all the CLI utilities. Is there a way to separate these two categories in my docker-compose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose up for only certain containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233105/docker-compose-up-for-only-certain-containers)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not really... I do not want the user to know what to start or even create a script only to start certain containers...

Comment: Docker compose is usually a dev tool - who *is* the user here? What are your constraints? What have you already considered and dismissed, and why?

Comment: Those "CLI utilities" sound like steps that should get run in your images' Dockerfiles, not things that would want separate containers.  How and when would you use a standalone `npm` container?  You can also `docker-compose run` commands based on your existing services, which might let you take these utility blocks out of your Compose setup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update

Starting with [`docker-compose` 1.28.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.28.0) the new [service profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) are just made for that! With `profiles` you can mark services to be only started in specific profiles:

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    # ...
  mysql:
    # ...
  composer:
    profiles: ["cli-only"]
    # ...
    # ...
  npm:
    profiles: ["cli-only"]
    # ...
```

```sh
docker-compose up # start main services, no composer and no npm
docker-compose run --rm composer
docker-compose run --rm npm
```

---

### original answer

Unfortunately there is currently no convenient way to do this. The officially recommended way to do it is to separate your commands into its own `docker-compose.yml`:

```sh
# start all your services
docker-compose up

# execute a defined command in docker-compose.cli.yml
docker-compose -f docker-compose.cli.yml run npm update

# if your command depends_on a service you need to merge the configs
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.cli.yml run npm update
```

Specifying multiple `docker-compose.yml` files with the `-f` flag will merge them together, see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files). This allows you to depend on services/networks/volumes which are defined in another file.

For an in-depth discussion on the whole issue see [docker/compose#1896](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1896).

Comment: Unfortunately with two separated files, I rely on networks and services that are declared in another file :(

Comment: @nowox see the third command then: you can specify multiple `docker-compose.yml` files which will be merged; I updated my answer to explain this and added a link to the relevant docs.

Comment: Wooh! I didn't get that far. Indeed this is exactly what I am looking for!